# Using INDEX, MATCH, and/or OFFSET to get the value of a column header if text is found in a range in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, flatten, google-query-language

I have a Google Sheet that acts as a weekly calendar for job duties. (first screenshot)
In each of the columns are drop-downs to select a name.

I have a separate sheet that I'm building out to be a dashboard. (second screenshot)

In my example, Michael Scott is in Bay 1A Monday and Tuesday, but in Bay 2 on Thursday and Friday.
What I need is to be able to return the appropriate bay number to the dashboard wherever Michael Scott's name shows up.

Hoping that explanation makes sense.

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that the drop-downs are a merge of columns O and P.

**EDIT 2** Current formula being used.
`=IF(IFERROR(CELL("contents",OFFSET(INDEX(FASHION!$J$10:$J$195,MATCH($C4,FASHION!$J$10:$J$195,0)),1,4)),"")="",IFERROR(CELL("contents",OFFSET(INDEX(FASHION!$J$10:$J$195,MATCH($C4,FASHION!$J$10:$J$195,0)),-6,4)),""),IFERROR(CELL("contents",OFFSET(INDEX(FASHION!$J$10:$J$195,MATCH($C4,FASHION!$J$10:$J$195,0)),-6,4)),""))`
Where cell C4 is the reference to the person's name.

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(QUERY(IF(
 FILTER(A8:J48, MOD(COLUMN(A8:J48), 2)=0)=L3, 
 FILTER(A2:J42, MOD(COLUMN(A2:J42)-1, 2)=0), ),,9^9)), 
 "(?i)bay ", ), " ", ", "))
```

[image]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PJFT77EpPm3TOKQjC0zk2yWt_6EaMjylCKBGgCXPLQA/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Can you explain why the two different FILTER functions are using different ranges? Not sure I understand that part.
I replaced all 4 of your ranges with the entire sheet on my end and I get an error that it can't overwrite a certain cell...which isn't even IN that range.

Comment: @Michael first filter checks for PH and 2nd filter returns the name. they are not different,  just offset. see the included demo sheet

Comment: the first filter uses range: A8:J48, while the second uses: A2:J42.
I changed both (all 4 range occurrences) to the same data range on my end and it doesn't work.

Comment: i made a test sheet and removed names...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d0SXXQxbd9mPQSjr6olDIzVdL6Gg8FWZtA9oVDQx9bo/edit?usp=sharing
Could you see if it works on this? Because I couldn't reproduce your result. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Michael sure, see your sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziW46.png

Comment: Hey @player0, where in that formula can I add the SBLANK function, so that I can add something to the cell by default if it's empty?

Comment: @Michael you can wrap it into regexreplace and do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wK7R.png